# How to generate dependencies in nuspec (or nupkg contains dependencies in its metadata) from csproj

Tags: c#, dependencies, continuous-integration, nuget

Say there is a solution, contains project A, B.

- A referenced B in traditional way. (add reference -> projects -> B)
- B depends only on .NET framework libs.

Here is what I do:

```
nuget pack A.csproj
```

It will generate A.nupkg **without**

```
<dependencies>
      <dependency id="B" version="3.0" />
</dependencies>
```

What I want is A.nupkg **contains** dependency on B in its metadata.

I know you can place an A.nuspec under the same folder of A.csproj, and set the dependence on B in A.nuspec. But it costs manual work to generate and maintain. Since A.csproj knows about B, is there any way that this can be done **without** manual work?

Or

Any suggestion on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Achieved this by add two targets in MSBuild build script:

```
<GenSpecCommand>$(NuGetCommand) spec -Force</GenSpecCommand>
<BuildCommand>$(NuGetCommand) pack "$(ProjectPath)" -p Configuration=$(Configuration) -o "$(PackageOutputDir)" -IncludeReferencedProjects</BuildCommand>
```

Hope it is useful for others.

Answer (score -1):

You can use "$version$", like this

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency id="YourPackage.Name" version="$version$" />
</dependencies>
```